# Error in generated xtick labels using coordindex

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I have a CSV file such as

```
time_    realval  NN      PF        UKF
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08777 0.08776
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08777 0.08776
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08777 0.08776
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08776 0.08776
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08776 0.08776
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08776 0.08776
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08776 0.08776
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08775 0.08775
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08775 0.08775
2:30:51 0.11408 0.11408 0.08775 0.08775
2:30:52 0.11408 0.11408 0.08775 0.08775
2:30:52 0.11408 0.11408 0.08775 0.08775
2:30:52 0.11408 0.11408 0.08774 0.08775
2:30:52 0.11408 0.11408 0.08774 0.08775
2:30:52 0.11408 0.11408 0.08774 0.08774
```

I am trying to plot values of each columns in a figure, but I do not want to plot all `xticks` labels, because it will not readable, so I used the following code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \subfloat
    {\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{all_methods_compare3.csv}\data
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
        xtick=data,
        xtick={1,100,...,800},
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
        xticklabels from table=\data{time_},
        ]
        \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=NN , col sep=comma] {all_methods_compare3.csv};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

so I expect to get `xticklabels` such `1,100,200,...,800` but I get the figure with the `xticklabels` like figure below:

[image: wrong xtick labels]

Interestingly enough, xlabels are in correct position, but the latex does not really run `x expr=\coordindex` command. It always read CSV files from top to bottom until number of `xticklabels` are equal to number `xticklabels` that I have defined, but it ignores the index.

I have used the same code, with different steps for different CSV file, and everything is just fine, the only difference between the above code and the CSV file that I have used, is that, the other CSV file are much bigger, and steps are bigger as well, but that is all. I also tried to define `xmin` and `xmax`, but it did not help as well.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Unfortunately your question and your provided code are quite unclear, so your final goal is quite unclear to me. It doesn't make any sense to use two different `xtick` keys and when you use `xtick=data` it doesn't make sense to provide the "same" labels by providing `xticklabels from table` when also providing `x expr=\coordindex`. Why not simply providing `x=time_` and `xtick distance=100`,  maybe together with appropriate `xmin` and `xmax` values?

Comment: Hello Stefan, I tried to use xtick distance, and worked, the problem is it does not work for non floating points. I update my question, and data set to present the issue a bit more transparent.

My data set has 800 samples, only 10 or 15 of the first samples have time stamp of 02:30:51, so even the second label should not be even 02:03:51,  is should be 2:45:55. But the latex, just count from 0 to 800 with the step of 100, and generate ids of 1, 2, .., 8 and then read the values of 1st, 2nd row of my data set.

Comment: I updated and simplified my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `xticklabels from table`, you get the first N rows of the table, it doesn't look up the line of the table corresponding to `\coordindex`. That doesn't make sense I think, the tick specification is separate from the plotted values.

You can perhaps use the following technique, with `xticklabel`, and reading the ticklabels manually from the table. See comments in code, ask if anything is unclear.

(I removed `col sep=comma` because the file you show doesn't use commas to separate the columns.)

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % loads pgfplots, which loads tikz
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \subfloat
    {\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\data
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
        xtick={0,100,...,800}, % start at 0, because \coordindex starts at zero
        xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
        xticklabel={%
          % \tick gives the tick value with decimals, use int to make it an integer
          % result of \pgfmathparse is saved in \pgfmathresult
          \pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}%
          % then read the value from the time_ column with the row number 
          % given by \pgfmathresult
          \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfmathresult}{t}\of\data% 
          % the value is saved to \pgfplotsretval, so issue that macro to print the ticklabel
          \pgfplotsretval
        },
        ]
        \addplot [] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=NN] {\data};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

To demonstrate that the approach works, I generated a data file with 801 rows, having time values similar to what you show (five values per second for my case), and random numbers for the  y-values. 801 rows are needed because `pgfplotstable` counts from zero, so for the last tick, `\pgfplotstablegetelem` looks up the 801st row. The output of the above code is then the following:

[image: sample output]

Comment: I do not know how to say thank you enough. I do appreciate your help. I was really frustrated and did not know what to do. I even started to use Python, matplotlib and things like. Was too slow, too messy, but I'd have to do it if you did not answer my question. Thanks again...