# How to keep xtick label in pgfplots for those coordinates wihout y value

Tags: pgfplots

I construct plots by coordinates from table. For some coordinates, 
the `y` value is not given which causes the related `xtick label` 
disappears. But I want these `xtick labels` for such coordinates being 
shown on my plots. How to do it?
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usepackage{filecontents} 

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat} 
time    id  a
59:58   1   1
59:59   2   4
00:00   3   nan
00:01   4   16
00:02   5   25
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={example},
xlabel=time,
ylabel={$data$},
xticklabel style={rotate=90},
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={test.dat}{time} 
]
\addplot [blue,mark=*] table[x=id,y=a] {test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the x axis is time, you can try using pgfplots library `dateplot` and then directly plot time vs data.

Comment: Thank you @nidhin. Yet, the x-axis has to be "id" in my case.

Comment: Is it okay if the `00:00` is not marked but other ticks appear at the correct place?

Comment: I'm afraid not. 00:00 is necessary in my  plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you could use `xtick={1,...,5}` instead of `xtick=data`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usepackage{filecontents} 

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat} 
time    id  a
59:58   1   1
59:59   2   4
00:00   3   nan
00:01   4   16
00:02   5   25
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={example},
xlabel=time,
ylabel={$data$},
xticklabel style={rotate=90},
xtick={1,...,5},
xticklabels from table={test.dat}{time} 
]
\addplot [blue,mark=*] table[x=id,y=a] {test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Torbjφm. In my example, there are only 5 lines of data. In fact, I have to plot nearly ten thousands lines of data, and some of them have "nan" data. And I want a xtick label at an interval every 900 lines.So how to use "xtick=" to solve my problem? Thank you.

Comment: @lyl Well, with 10000 points you definitely don't want `xtick=data` anyways. Perhaps`xtick={1,901,...,10000}`.

Comment: @lyl Sorry, I forgot about the `xticklabels from table`. that makes it a bit more tricky, but I think I have another answer describing a possible method. Give me a couple of minutes, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @lyl See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424357/error-in-generated-xtick-labels-using-coordindex/424587#424587